# git: how to handle multiple branches, and pending pull requests

Tags: git, github

I've got a git repo fork.

I've made a branch `branch-1` and have a pending PR on the `origin/master`

I want to fix another issue, which I think needs to be put in a new branch `branch-2`

`branch-1` has some fixes that I would like to see in `branch-2` (without `branch 1`, tests will not pass, and life will be annoying)

I don't want to wait for the PR to be merged to begin work on `branch-2` in my fork.

How would you go about this situation without causing complications down the line...

Comment: There is no avoiding at least part of the pull request on `branch-1` as far as I know.  Maybe you could cancel the first pull request, and branch off `branch-1` at an earlier point.  Then do the `branch-2` work, create a pull request, and finally return to `branch-1` to finish it.

Comment: Just start `branch-2` from the current state of `branch-1`, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @meagar, will that result in a headache down the line if the PR is merged, other commits come in on top of `branch-1`'s merge commit and then I submit a PR for branch 2? Sometimes I choose the wrong path in git and end up with a huge headache down the line...

Comment: No, there is no headache except that if branch-2 is merged before branch-1, merging branch-1 will be a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

> will that result in a headache down the line if the PR is merged, other commits come in on top of branch-1's merge commit and then I submit a PR for branch 2?

In that case (additional commits done on top of the accepted and merged branch-1), all you need to do is rebase branch-2 on top of the updated upstream/master (upstream reference the original repo you have forked)

```
 cd /path/to/your/repo
 git fetch upstream
 git reset master upstream/master
 git rebase --onto master branch-1 branch-2
```

That will rebase your local commits done from your local brnach-1 HEAD (excluded) up to your branch-2 HEAD (included) ontop of the updated original repo `master`.

Then you can force push branch-2; your existing branch-2 PR will be updated.